# Many Duplicate Queries in Entity Framework 5 Code-First(n+1)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

One of our contractors implemented a repository pattern with code first approach. We use Service Locator as DI pattern. what we do when we retrieve data from DB, we pass interface to GetQueryable function and get the data. However, I see serious performance issues on our application. I implemented MiniProfiler and MiniProfiler.EF to see where the bottleneck is.

We have a case table which has quite a few fields(around 25) and some of those fields are associated to other tables as one to one and one to many(only one field has many relation to other table). when I try to see the case detail, it runs around 400 SQL queries and SQL takes around 40 percent of the load time as far as the miniprofiler concerned. Here our GetQueryable and Find methods

```
      public IQueryable<T> GetQueryable<T>(params string[] includes)
    {
        Type type = _impls.Value[typeof (T).Name].GetType();
        DbSet dbSet = Db.Set(type);
        foreach (var include in includes)
        {
            dbSet.Include(include);
        }
        return ((IQueryable<T>) dbSet);
    }
```

I added included to this method to attach other related tables, but it did not make any difference. and here is the Find Method

```
  public T Find<T>(long? id)
    {
        Type type = _impls.Value[typeof(T).Name].GetType();
        return (T) Db.Set(type).Find(id);
    }
```

I pretty much tried to apply all the performance improvements, but the number of the SQL queries has not gone down. I tried to disable lazy loading, but it caused many problems in other parts of the application.

Just some additional information, in case table, there are 70000 rows and in out dialogs table, there are 500000 rows. Case and Dialog are associates as one-to-many. and each case has 20-40 dialog entries.

My questions are;

- Why does include not make any difference when I use?
- Is there any other way to crop number of the queries run?
- Do you think the implementation is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: What is your underlying query?  `Include` only works if you aren't transforming the original query.  Your query must return the object type you began the query with.  Can you post what the Db class does?

Comment: Basically the query is, var case = Locator.Facade.GetQueryableFor<ICaseData>().Sincle(k=>k.Id == caseId);

Comment: I wonder if the `Db.Set` is causing undesirable effects on the query.  Can you show us what that code does?

Comment: Which code? The one one the question?

Comment: The class that houses Db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Fire your contractor. Seriously. Like right now. That is some *awful* code. Not only did they miss something as simple and basic as using the generic version of `Set`, but they've successfully only made working with Entity Framework more complex, because all the repository does is proxy Entity Framework methods with its own unique and bastardized API.

That said, there's really not enough here to diagnose what your problem is. The use of `Include` may give you *larger* queries, but it should actually serve to reduce the overall number of queries issued. It's possible, you're just not using includes where you should be.

Now, the fact that you "tried to disable lazy loading, but it caused many problems in other parts of the application", means that you're relying too heavily on lazy-loading. Basically, you're loading in stuff you don't even know about, which is the antithesis of optimization. Ironically, you'd actually be best served by going ahead and disabling lazy-loading, and then tracking down where your code fails because of that. If you want to actually lazy-load that thing, you can use `.Load` (see: [Explicit Loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#explicit)). But, if you want to eager-load to reduce queries, then you know what includes you need to add.

Answer (score 2):

`Include` **returns** a new `IQueryable` and does not modify the source query. In addition you can use the generic version of `Set` which simplifies the code a bit:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetQueryable<T>(params string[] includes)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = Db.Set<T>();
    foreach (var include in includes)
    {
        query = query.Include(include);
    }
    return query;
}
```

Comment: I will try, but do you think it will make me gain some performance?

Comment: @AnarchistGeek: It will make the `Include` work as it should. This *might* reduce the number of your 400 queries because lazy loading is not required anymore (assuming that you apply the *right* includes).